# Are Pull Requests to a BSD project also BSD?

Tags: github, bsd

Suppose on GitHub one has a BSD project. If people make changes and and then request for you to pull them, are those changes also BSD licensed by default?

Answer (score 6):

Per Github [TOS](https://help.github.com/articles/github-terms-of-service/#6-contributions-under-repository-license) help page:

> 6. Contributions Under Repository License
>
> Whenever you make a contribution to a repository containing notice of a license, you license your contribution under the same terms, and you agree that you have the right to license your contribution under those terms. If you have a separate agreement to license your contributions under different terms, such as a contributor license agreement, that agreement will supercede.
>
> Isn't this just how it works already? Yep. This is widely accepted as the norm in the open-source community; it's commonly referred to by the shorthand "inbound=outbound". We're just making it explicit.

So yes on Github, contributions are under the project's license (e.g. BSD-licensed in your case), unless stated otherwise.